# Empathy sets status to "offline" when I set it to "invisible"?

Tags: fedora, gnome3, accounts, empathy

my system is Fedora 18 and my empathy version is 3.6.4, when I change the Empathy status to invisible, it changes to offline and contact lists disappear and my profile status changes to unavailable(the top-right corner of the screen). as you see...

[image: image description]

the only difference between this state and "offline mode" is : when I choose invisible and this state happens, I am still connected, because when I choose available, I can see the contact list instantly and it doesn't need to connect again to my accounts.

I updated the whole system , but I still have this problem.